# How to implement ringing in outgoing Android VOIP call

Tags: java, android, voip, voice, agora.io

We are using agora.io for voice calling in our app(VOIP). The calls between two people are going seemless. But when I am dialing person B, I am not able to hear the dial tone while the call is being connected. I basically want to hear the ringing when the call is being connect. However, the person is getting the incoming caller tune while his phone is ringing.

Can you anyone help me how to do this?

We are building Android App, Java, Kotlin, and Agora.io SDK

Comment: Prabhakar, if the answer below worked for you, would you please confirm it as the correct response?

Comment: Done. Thank you for reminding, @Hermes

Comment: Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently Agora.io's Android SDK does not directly support playing audio on the caller side. This would need to be achieved using Android's [Telcom](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/package-summary) package, more specifically implementing [Connection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Connection.html#onPostDialContinue(boolean)), [ConnectionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService.html) and [ToneGenerator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator) classes.

Whenever you start your call you may want to create a new tone, replacing `<AUDIO STREAM>` below with the stream that you want to play the tone within, and replacing `<VOLUME LEVEL>` with an integer (or enum) to set the volume level.

```
ToneGenerator dtmfGenerator = new ToneGenerator(<AUDIO STREAM>,<VOLUME LEVEL>);
dtmfGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 1000); 
dtmfGenerator.stopTone();
```

For example if you want to leverage the Call tone using the above example, you would use [ToneGenerator.TONE_SUP_RINGTONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html#TONE_SUP_RINGTONE)

```
ToneGenerator dtmfGenerator = new ToneGenerator(ToneGenerator.TONE_SUP_RINGTONE,ToneGenerator.MAX_VOLUME);
dtmfGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 1000); 
dtmfGenerator.stopTone();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are working in Flutter, the [flutter_dtmf](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dtmf) package does this...

```dart
import 'package:flutter_dtmf/dtmf.dart';

...
Dtmf.playTone("1", durationMs: 1000);
```